# RDP to WinXP Machine Denied

Tags: windows-xp, security, remote-desktop

I've got a Windows XP workstation that I'm trying to access via RDP.

It keeps giving me the following error when I try to log in using RDP:

```
The local policy of this system does not permit you to logon interactively.
```

- The user is in the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group.
- RDP is enabled on the workstation
- The Local security policy has `Administrators` and `Remote Desktop Users` allowed for Terminal Services
- Only ASPNET is denied for Terminal Services

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

An account with a blank passwd will do this.